# Using Validation Tag Helper in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET 5 app. I'm creating this app as a learning exercise on a Mac. Currently, I'm trying to use the validation tag helper. In my view, I have the following code:

```
<form method="POST" action="~/account/login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div class="validation" asp-validation-summary="All" />

    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new {  })


    <input id="Username" name="Username" />
    <br />

    <input id="Password" name="Password" />
    <br />

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</form>
```

The traditional `@Html.ValidationSummary(...)` approach works. However, the `<div class="validation" asp-validation-summary="All" />` approach does not. I want to break away from using the tradition `@Html.` approach and use tag helpers as much as possible.

Why won't the validation results appear in the `asp-validation-summary`?

Thank you!

Comment: are you doing it with both on the page, or are you removing the `@Html` version when you're testing the tag helper?

Comment: @DLeh I've tried it with and without. I tried with `@Html` just to ensure my validation was happening. Then, I removed `@Html` to see if it was some how causing a conflict. Either way, the `@Html` approach shows the validation errors. The `asp-validation-summary` approach does not :(. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you said you're creating it on a mac, I though the new tag helpers were only present in the latest visual studio CTP?

Comment: I didn't think visual studio was a requirement. I thought it was all about the packages you reference.

Comment: Are other taghelpers working? Have you used the `@addtaghelper` in your view? Does the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers` is referenced in your project?

Comment: @nemesv I have `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers` listed as a dependency in `project.json`.  Then, in `_GlobalImport.cshtml` I have `@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this [commit](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/9b2a9e397649a928f85f323fe44a915af260035a)
the `ValidationSummaryTagHelper` takes a value of the `ValidationSummary` enum instead of a `string`

So you need to write:

```
<div class="validation" asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All" />
```

See also in the sample on [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/9b2a9e397649a928f85f323fe44a915af260035a/samples/TagHelperSample.Web/Views/Home/Edit.cshtml#L9).

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. Please see my last comment above. It appears that no tag helpers are working.

Comment: Have you tried to add the `@addtaghelper "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"` to a `ViewStart.cshtml` inside a views folder instead of the `_GlobalImport.cshtml`? Also which versions of MVC and `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers` are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your persistence. When I add `@addtaghelper ...` to `_ViewStart.cshtml`, I receive an error that says: `Views\_ViewStart.cshtml(4,7): error CS0103: The name 'addTagHelper' does not exist in the current context`. In regards to the versions of MVC and TagHelpers, here is what is in my `project.json` file:  `    "dependencies": {
        "Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-*"
    },`

Comment: Ah ha. The problem was the fact the traditional ASP.NET anti forgery token attribute in the controller. Once I removed the attribute, everything worked.